# cannot convert value of type, swift 2.0, error handling

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform, swift2

```
func refreshResults() {

    let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let theHeight = view.frame.size.height

    messageX = 37.0
    messageY = 26.0

    messageArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    senderArray.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)

    let innerP1 = NSPredicate(format: "sender = %@ AND other = %@", userName, otherName)
    var innerQ1: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Messages", predicate: innerP1)

    let innerP2 = NSPredicate(format: "sender = %@ AND other = %@", otherName, userName)
    var innerQ2: PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Messages", predicate: innerP2)

    var query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([innerQ1, innerQ2] )
    query.addAscendingOrder("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in // this is line with error

        if error == nil {
            for object in objects! {
                self.senderArray.append(object.objectForKey("sender") as! String)
                self.messageArray.append(object.objectForKey("message") as! String)
            }
        } 
    } 
}
```

Using Swift 2.0 I get the error

```
'cannot convert value of type [AnyObject]?, NSError? -> void to expected argument type PFQueryArrayResultBlock'
```

I figured out that it's because of new error handling in Swift 2.0, but I am still not figuring out what I need to do to fix this.

Comment: Can you find and add the definition of `PFQueryArrayResultBlock` to your question.  It's probably just a matter of making your block's signature match the defined signature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with Parse Query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32580364/error-with-parse-query-findobjectsinbackgroundwithblock)

Comment: Please google before you ask questions.

Comment: My bad, I didn't realize there was a duplicate! Will be more thorough with that next time. Cheers!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
**(objects:[PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in**
```

Parse changed, and recommends to use PFObject